# Creating a non-zeta-ified sum

Tags: evaluation, special-functions, summation

The expression

```
Sum[i^(-s), {i, 1, ∞}]
```

evaluates to

```
Zeta[s]
```

But, of course, this is not strictly correct as `Zeta` is defined where the sum is not. It is a continuation of it.

The result is that one can get results like

```
TrueQ[(Sum[i^(-s), {i, 1, ∞}] /. s -> -1) == Sum[i, {i, 1, ∞}]]
```

giving

```
False
```

Is there a way of preventing Mathematica from doing this continuation/regularisation step when dealing with sums (also, I'd like to know for cases of where factorials get converted to Gamma, but that might be a different question).

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html

Comment: @J.M. sure, but surely I can stop it... can't I?

Comment: You mean, like what `Sum[i^(-s), {i, 1, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]` does?

Comment: @J.M. No, so that, for example, if I do `F[s_] = Sum[i^(-s), {i, 1, \[Infinity]}]`, calling `F[-1]` says that it does not converge. Or if I do `F[s_] := Sum[i^(-t), {i, 1, \[Infinity]}] /. t -> s`

Comment: If you use `:=` instead of `=` in your first definition, you get warned whenever you stray from the usual domain of Riemann $\zeta$.

Comment: @J.M. yeah, sure, that's why I included the second example. Can I just stop it from trying to be clever? I would have thought that `Sum[i^(-s), {i, 1, \[Infinity]}, Regularization -> None]` would do what I want, as in, only return zeta where it is defined. I want a representation of the sum, not the zeta function.